# Problems from CSIR Question Paper (Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $K\subset \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded set. Let $H(\mathbb{C})$ denote the set of all entire functions and let $C(K)$ denote the set of all continuous functions on $K$. Consider the restriction map $r:H(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow C(K)$ by $r(f)=f|_K.$ Then $r$ is injective if

1. $K$ is compact
2. $K$ is connected
3. $K$ is uncountable
4. $K$ is finite.

I need $r$ is injective, i.e., $r(f)=r(g)$ implies $f|_K=g|_K$ implies $f=g.$ From here I cannot find conditions on $K$. Please some one help me.

Answer (score 3):

By the identity principle, if $f$ and $g$ are entire functions that agree on a set with accumulation points, they agree everywhere.

The only one of the four conditions stated that guarantees $K$ having accumulation points is (3). You should be able to come up with counterexamples to the other three. (Take $K$ as a single point.)

In fact, since you assume that $K$ is bounded, the "un" in "uncountable" is superfluous.